# How to replace ID with Town names?

Tags: php, sql, replace

How can I replace category id? Now it's 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 and so on. I want to replace them all with town names. E.g. 1=Tokyo, 2=Budapest, 3=Copenhagen.

```php
$sql = "SELECT pic, title, address, category FROM wp_23444423 WHERE COALESCE(pic, '') != '' ORDER BY id DESC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<br> <img src="'.$row['pic'].'"><br>Name: '. $row['title']. '<br>Coordinates: ' . $row['address'] . '<br>Category: ' . $row['category'] . '<br>';
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Do you have some table that contains id and name of those towns?

Comment: You should add what language you are working in, since it's not purely SQL (it looks like PHP). Also which SQL version you are using (e.g. MySQL). If you have any control of the database though, this should be an issue of joining, as @barbsan already hinted...

Comment: @Noceo I added sql tag, because I think it could be solved by joining certain table, this doesn't seem to be php related issue (sure, OP uses php but most propably the query has to be changed) and as well it doesn't seem to depend on database type

Comment: Hi all, no i just want to add PHP code which replaces all data from category column for example 1 should be replaced to Tokyo, 2 to Budapest and so on.. @barbsan No

Comment: @Noceo check my answer above. I just want to use PHP to replace all id's.

Comment: @user11102573 then feel free to remove sql tag and add php tag. Do you have some array with these towns? You have to define somewhere which town should be assigned to given id

Answer (score 0):

Based on you comments, I would say that you are looking the the [switch statement](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_switch.asp). Create a city name variable and set it, depending on the switch input (which would be the category id). Something like this:

```
switch (categoryId) {
    case 1:
        $cityName = "Tokyo";
        break;
    case label2:
        $cityName = "Budapest";
        break;
    case label3:
        $cityName = "Copenhagen";
        break;
    ...
    default:
        $cityName = "Unknown city";
}
```

I would still recommend looking into joining in SQL though, since this would be both cleaner and faster...

Also, this approach is based on the assumption that you don't have an insane amount of city names. If you have a lot of cities, you might be better off creating an array or dictionary (I am not quite sure of the options in php) an look up through that. Or to make a table in the database, of course.